# Significance of Names

Tags: names

It is well known that one's name has profound significance regarding his/her essence. The name itself is important, as is the name along with the father's and mother's name.

My question is, what other pieces of information would be important to an assessment of a name. For example, if the Vilna Gaon or Arizal were to analyze a person by his name, what information would they want to see for the assessment to be comprehensive.

Does a surname have significance; does a nickname (e.g., Yonatan called Nati) have significance? Does the person's job or location have significance?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ha'Azinu.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en